# Show that $V = \emptyset.$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, connectedness

The question says:

Let $I = [0,1]$. Suppose $I = U \bigcup V$ is a separation of $I,$ and that $0 \in U.$ Show that $V = \emptyset.$

**My trial:**

I got a hint if $V \neq \emptyset,$ then I can use the following problem:

Let $U \subseteq I$ be an open set (but not all of $I$), and assume that $0 \in U.$ 
Show that there is a number $a \in (0,1]$ such that $U = [0,a) \bigcup W,$ where $W$ is also open in $I$ and $W \bigcap [0,a) = \emptyset.$

**But I still confused about how to use this problem, could anyone help me please?**

Comment: What is $I$ here?

Comment: @CameronWilliams the unit interval

Comment: $I$ is connected, this is the key for your problem: it cannot be the union of two disjoints sets (excepting obviously with the empty set).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A=\{x\in[0,1]\mid[0,x]\subset U\}$. Since $0\in U$ and $U$ is an open subset of $[0,1]$, $A\neq\emptyset$. And $A$ is bounded, since it is a subset of $[0,1]$. Therefore, it makes sense to talk about $s=\sup A$.

Sunce $s\in[0,1]=U\cup V$, $s\in U$ or $s\in V$. But, since $V$ is an open subset of $[0,1]$, if $s\in V$, then $(s-\varepsilon,s]\subset V$ for some $\varepsilon>0$. Therefore, $(s-\varepsilon,s]$ would have no element of $U$. But this goes agains the definition os $s$ as $\sup\{x\in[0,1]\mid[0,x]\subset U\}$. So, $s\in U$. But then $[0,s]\subset U$.

And we cannot have $s<1$ because then, since $s\in U$ and $U$ is open, $[0,s+\varepsilon)\subset U$ for some $\varepsilon>0$ and so $s+\varepsilon\in A$, which is impossible, since $s+\varepsilon>s=\sup A$.

So, $s=1$, and therefore $V=\emptyset$, which is impossible.

Comment: and how these two problems together with the knowledge that "every open set in $\mathbb{R}$ is a union of disjoint open intervals" tell us that the interval $[0,1] $ is connected?

Comment: I proved that if $[0,1]=U\cup V$ with $U$ and $V$ open is disjoint can happen only when $U$ or $V$ is empty. That is what being connected *means*.

Comment: Could you please if you have time look at the definition of $W'$ here I am a little bit confused about the last line, I do not understand it  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3546375/open-subsets-of-the-closed-unit-interval

Comment: I do not understand this statement "Therefore, $(s-\varepsilon,s]$ would have no element of $U$" is this because $U \cup V$ is a separation of I?

Comment: Yes. Since $(s-\varepsilon]\subset V$ and since $U\cap V=\emptyset$, $U\cap(s-\varepsilon]=\emptyset$.